# wooCommerce Rest API (PHP 7.4) cannot view/edit users (rest_user_cannot_view)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, store, webshop

I am using the [Automattic Client](https://github.com/Automattic/woocommerce-services) to connect to wooCommerce Rest API and most of the requests work fine. Usually I am using the Endpoint `wc/v3` but I changed to `wp/v2` since it seems that user/customer roles can only be edited with this one and we need to edit them through API now.
Calling the Url `https://my_webshop/wp-json/wp/v2/users/{user_id}` always results in `rest_user_cannot_view - Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.`

The following Code is used to connect to the client:

```
$options = array(
  'return_as_array' => false,
  'validate_url' => false,
  'timeout' => 30,
  'ssl_verify' => false,
  'version' => "wp/v2" //added to access user endpoint
);

//$options['query_string_auth'] = "true"; //tried this one because other posts said query string authentication may help
   
$client= new Client(
  $store_url,
  $consumer_key,
  $consumer_secret,
  $options
);

$client->get("users/{user_id}");
```

I also tried using username/password instead of consumer_key and secret but still no success.
According to the [authentication documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) `Basic Authentication` should work fine.

Using the `X-WP-Nonce` and `Cookie` from the result headers after a browser client login and adding them to the client headers lists the expected users but only as long as the current browser session is logged in.
I guess if there is a way to get these parameters through API that would work too but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround (from Mayrhofer): I found a solution using the [WordPress REST API Authentication](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-authentication/) plugin by miniOrange. If the installed client authentication is selected, then the process works using the webshop's client credentials (not the key & secret). I still don't know why its not working with key/secret but at least I can update the groups now.